# Background threads handling TCP connections in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I'm making a Rails 4 app, where I need to keep multiple TCP connections open towards another server. What would be the best way to implement the background threads serving these connections? Or should I use non-blocking sockets?

I have features that require the HTTP serving thread to wait for the response in the background connection, but other times the background threads need to write the DB.

Most libraries handling background threads are pretty much job oriented (e.g. Sidekiq), it seems they could not handle spawning a new thread for each new connection. I tried to make it with the Thread class and mutexes, but strange stuff seems to happen (like background threads stopping for no reason, then reappearing, but that might be a quirk of byebug).